# Toggle values in observableArray Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

Basically I have a list and each item in the list has a unique value.  If a list item is clicked on, I want the value to be added or removed from an observable array.  So if that value exists in the array, I want to remove it and vice-versa.

The structure of the array would be simple:

```
var items = ko.observableArray([
    "value1",
    "value2"
]);
```

The list will have inputs with `value1` and `value2`.  If the list with `value2` is clicked on, I want to remove it from the array, and if it doesn't, I need to `push` it to the array.

So basically I need to toggle an item in the array.

Is this possible with knockout.js?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Knockout's observableArray has an `indexOf` method built right in.  Use it, along with `push` and `remove` to do what you're asking.  Something like this should work:

```
function toggle(value){
    if (items.indexOf(value) < 0){
        //it's not in the array - push it
        items.push(value);
    } else {
        //it's there - remove it
        items.remove(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier.  For some reason the code pushes the value, but removes it right after.  It's like the if else doesn't work....

Comment: It toggles the value twice basically... Except when I add an alert() it only does it once.  o.O  I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: I am binding this to a `tap` function, not click...perhaps that's the problem

Comment: Possibly.  *Something* else is wrong.  The approach above is the way to go, though